# Solid State Relay in NC configuration

Tags: power-supply, ac, relay, solid-state-relay, triac

Is it possible to build an SSR relay circuit for controlling 240VAC (using TRIAC and other components) with NC configuration?
The idea is to keep the AC circuit closed, even when there are failures in the driver side (like a power supply failure or some control side failure)

Answer (score 0):

They're widely available commercially from more than a dozen suppliers around the globe, so the answer is "yes" it is possible.

Comment: Can you share the components used and a circuit diagram?

Comment: I don't have the internal circuit diagrams- manufacturers are not keen on sharing their proprietary designs. There are a variety of ways of going about it, but basically it boils down to using the AC power to trigger the triac and inhibiting that when an input is presented. One more-or-less obvious way would be to use a HV depletion-mode MOSFET and a bridge rectifier with a PV optoisolator driving the gate.